# Why is everything in python language an object if python is written in C?

Tags: python, c, interpreter

It is said: "Everything in python is an object." But python is written in C and C is not an object-oriented programming language. I am aware that C has the capabilty to implement some object-oriented concepts, but shouldn't it be called a struct or somethin instead of object?

Please clear up this mystery for me. Thank you.

Comment: at some point everything is machine code language, even compiled C++... C code of python implements object oriented concepts. that's all.

Comment: You could do object oriented C if you wanted to, using function pointers as methods and structures as classes.

Comment: My bicycle is composed of  wheels and frame. But neither wheels are bicycle, nor the frame is. How can it be? See [Fallacy of Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_division)

Comment: ... which says "If a system as a whole has some property that none of its constituents has, this is sometimes called an *emergent* property of the system."

Comment: @EugeneSh. Arguably the [Fallacy of Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_composition) applies here, depending on whether you look at "(supposed) inability to do object-oriented" or "is object-oriented" as the property. =)

Comment: @Arkku Well, these two are tightly related. I presume the basic OP's premise is "If python is OO then stuff python is build of has to be OO". That's division. Anyway, we are not on logic or philosophy site, so we cane loosen the strictness of the semantics:)

Answer (score 9):

First of all, there is nothing forcing a Python compiler written in C to have OO design internally. To assuming that the compiler must have that, is kind of like saying "in order to paint a house red, you must use a brush with a red handle". There is no relation between how a tool looks and the result produced with the aid of that tool.

Similarly, nothing is stopping you from using the red brush to paint your house blue. That is, nothing is stopping you from using a Python compiler to write non-OO programs.

For the same reasons, the first C++ compilers were written in C.

---

Regarding the subject of OO, there is no such thing as "object-oriented languages". Object-orientation is a way to do *program design* and it is not related to a specific language.

There are languages with support for OO features and there are languages that lack such support. Your program does not automatically turn OO just because you wrote it in Python. It is perfectly possible for your design to be a complete mess. Similarly, it is quite possible to write OO programs in C.

Contrary to popular belief, C actually does support all of the most important OO features:

- Autonomous objects only concerned about their own designated task, with limited coupling to the outside world. This is the single-most important thing in OO and completely language-independent, as it is 100% program design.
- Private encapsulation. Done through "opaque type"/"opaque pointers". You can achieve full private/protected encapsulation with these. Not nearly as convenient as in languages with built-in OO support through `class` + `private`, but quite possible.

  (Also, far more crude, there is "poor man's private" with `static` file scope variables, which may or may not be an acceptable means to do private encapsulation, depending on the application.)
- Inheritance and polymorphism. Again through "opaque type" combined with function pointers. By using function pointers, you kind of generate the whole virtual function look-up table manually, instead of having the compiler fixing this for you. Again, it is not nearly as pretty as in other languages but possible.

What C does not support is various other convenient language features such as constructors/destructors/RAII, that make OO programming a whole lot easier.

Comment: Thank you for this awesome response

Answer (score 0):

Python is a language - that is, a grammar and syntax. As such it's not "written" in C nor in any other programming language.

Implementations of the Python language (of any language actually) can be written in mostly any other turing-complete language,  there are Python implementations in C (the reference one also known as CPython), Java (named Jython), one for the .net runtime (don't ask me which language it was implemented with - probably C# but...), and Pypy which is implemented in RPython which itself is a subset of Python.

To make a long story short: a language has nothing to do with the (possibly various) technologies used to implement that language.

Comment: I meant the python interpreter is written in C.

Comment: @benbitdiddle Nope. The _CPython_ runtime is written in C - but there ARE other Python runtimes are written in other languages. FWIW the first C compilers where written in assembly (now they are most written in C), and you could perfectly write a C compiler in Python or Java or whatever turing-complete language. In the end, it all ends up as electric current in logical circuits. Is electric current "object oriented" ?